Cannot access static files
I have a django website I just deployed but nginx is not serving the site's static files and I don't know if my nginx configuration is wrong or not. All my static files return a 404 error.
Here is my nginx configurations file
upstream founders_app_server {
        server unix:/home/founders/founders/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name founderslooking.com;

        client_max_body_size 4G;

        location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

                proxy_redirect off;

                if (!-f $request_filename) {
                        proxy_pass http://founders_app_server;
                }
        }
        location /static {
                autoindex on;
                root /home/founders/founders/back/static;
        }
}




Does this answer your question? Nginx -- static file serving confusion with root & alias
